# Oracle Stored Procedure runs with ORA-01007 variable not in select list

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, dynamic-sql

I got a Stored Procedure (compiled with no error/warning) like following :

```sql
create or replace procedure my_schema.SP_UPDATE_MEMBER(noP in varchar2, nameP in varchar2, idNoP in varchar2, birthdayP in varchar2, emailP in varchar2, phoneP in varchar2, passwordP in varchar2, tableP in varchar2)
is
v_prg_name varchar2(20) := 'SP_UPDATE_MEMBER';
v_cnt      number(8)    := 0;
sys_sql    varchar2(1000);

begin
  Insertlog(SYSDATE, v_prg_name, '1.0 Start'); --It's a simple log, tried remove it didn't solve my problem
  sys_sql :=  sys_sql || 'update '|| tableP || ' set ';
  if nameP is not null then
    sys_sql :=  sys_sql || '       name=''' || nameP || ''',';
  end if;
  if idNoP is not null then
    sys_sql :=  sys_sql || '       id_no=''' || idNoP || ''',';
  end if;
  if birthdayP is not null then
    sys_sql :=  sys_sql || '       birthday=to_date(''' || birthdayP || ''',''yyyy/MM/dd''),';
  end if;
  if emailP is not null then
    sys_sql :=  sys_sql || '       email=''' || emailP || ''',';
  end if;
  if phoneP is not null then
    sys_sql :=  sys_sql || '       mobile=''' || phoneP || ''',';
  end if;
  if passwordP is not null and length(passwordP) > 0 then 
    sys_sql :=  sys_sql || '       password=md5_hash(''' || passwordP || '''),';
  end if;
    sys_sql :=  sys_sql || '       no=''' || noP || ''' '; --I put it to prevent from , issue
    sys_sql :=  sys_sql || 'where  no=''' || noP || '''';

  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sys_sql INTO v_cnt;
  commit;
  Insertlog(SYSDATE, v_prg_name, '2.0 Finished w/o error'); --It's a simple log, tried remove it didn't solve my problem

  exception
  when others then
    declare
      error_time VARCHAR2(30) := RTRIM(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'YYYY/MM/DD, HH24:MI:SS'));
      error_code NUMBER := SQLCODE;
      error_msg  VARCHAR2(300) := SQLERRM;
    begin
      rollback;
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(error_time || ',' || TO_CHAR(error_code) || ',' || error_msg); --It's a simple log, tried remove it didn't solve my problem
      Insertlog(SYSDATE, v_prg_name,  error_msg || ', 3.0 ERROR, sql:' || sys_sql); --It's a simple log, tried remove it didn't solve my problem
    end;
end;
/
```

And call it in TOAD with this script (Feedback with **Method Called** and no error message) :

```sql
call my_schema.SP_UPDATE_MEMBER('00112233','UserName','A123456789','1970/01/01','somemail@mail.com','0912346578','123abc','member');
```

But member data didn't update, so I check my error log, it says :

```sql
ORA-01007: variable not in select list, 3.0 ERROR, sql:
update member
set    name='UserName',
       id_no='A123456789',
       birthday=to_date('1970/01/01','yyyy/MM/dd'),
       email='somemail@mail.com',
       mobile='0912345678',
       password=md5_hash('123abc'),
       no='00112233'
       where  no='00112233'
```

I didn't find where will cause this ORA-01007 error, may you help me to find it? or some hint ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You execute your assembled statement like this:

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sys_sql INTO v_cnt;
```

But it's an UPDATE statement, it returns nothing. So the INTO clause is wrong.

Presumably you want to know how many rows were updated? Try this:

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sys_sql;
v_cnt := sql%rowcount;
```

Comment: By remove that INTO v_cnt, my problem finally solved, thank you for saving my time~